# Oracle SQL: merge with more conditions than matched/not matched

Tags: sql, oracle, merge

I'm needing some help with a MERGE command in Oracle. Basically I have this command but I want to optimize it a little more:

```
MERGE INTO swap USING dual ON (SELECT id FROM student WHERE number = '123') 
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
  UPDATE SET swapped = 1, last_swap = sysdate 
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
  INSERT (student_id, swapped, last_swap) VALUES ((SELECT id FROM student WHERE number= '123'), 1, sysdate)
```

Right now this will insert or update a register on SWAP table. However, I would like to protect it from inserting NULL on the student_id if there's no student with that number on STUDENT table (I don't want to simply not allow NULL values on sudent_id of SWAP table).
Other thing, I'm repeating `SELECT id FROM student WHERE number = '123'` two times, how can I change this to execute it only once (store the result in an alias or something)?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your merge statement should use the "Select from student" as the table you are merging from. 
Can you post some sample data as well?

The below query is assuming that ID is the column on which you are merging and it cannot be null.

```
MERGE INTO swap 
      USING (SELECT id FROM student WHERE number = '123' and id is not null) stu
      on (stu.id = swap.id)
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
  UPDATE SET swapped = 1, last_swap = sysdate 
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
  INSERT (student_id, swapped, last_swap) VALUES (stu.id , 1, sysdate);
```